# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 using vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, d3.js, treemap

I am trying to create a treemap based on data from a `.json`. I am using d3 and vue with to help the process. When I try and load my data using the `d3.json()` function and outputting to console I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

```js
d3.json('./warehouses').then(function(error,data) {
  data = data.concat(json)
  render(data)
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: sounds like the API is returning HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: okay, im not too advanced in html, how could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load a json file, you should import it.
the code looks like this: 
`import data from '../addressOfJsonFile/db.json';` 
then you can use data variable you imported as your json object. note that you can name your json imported whatever you want.